# JBOSS FUSE Bundle is waiting for namespace handlers in GracePeriod

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I tried to add bean into blueprint.

Added CXF namespace. But, JBOSS FUSE shows

```
13:10:28,339 | INFO  | NAPSHOT-thread-1 | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 14 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.0.1.redhat-60024 | Bundle camel-basic is waiting for namespace handlers [http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf]
```

So, I remove the cxf and added blueprint namespace

```
http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
```

But, still no use, It shows same error for this namespace also.

Do I need to change anything in pom, blueprint.xml r need install anything in jboss fuse?

I have no clue about this.

blueprint.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd  
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint  http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">


<camelContext id="blueprintContext"
                trace="false"
                xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route id="httpBridge">
        <from uri="jetty:http://localhost:8282/service_sample_proxy/services_proxy/WebserviceClassPort?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
        <process ref="downloadLogger"/>
        <to uri="jetty:http://localhost:8080/service_sample/services/WebserviceClassPort?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>
        <process ref="downloadLogger"/>
        <to uri="bean:helloBean"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>  

  <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="webserviceProxy"
                     address="http://localhost:8383/service_sample_proxy/services_proxy/WebserviceClassPort"
                     endpointName="tns:WebserviceClassPort"
                     serviceName="tns:WebserviceClassService"
                     wsdlURL="wsdl/webserviceclass.wsdl"
                   xmlns:tns="http://webservice/" />

  <bean id="helloBean" class="org.fusesource.example.HelloBean" />

<bean id="downloadLogger" class="org.fusesource.example.DownloadLogger"/>  

</blueprint>
```

I haven't used this bean in any place. First I need to resolve this problem then I need to use it in route.

I check the

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install all needed features into your Fuse container (see [here](http://camel.apache.org/cxf-example-osgi-blueprint.html) for more information):

```
features:addUrl mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.9.0/xml/features
features:install war
features:install cxf
features:install camel-jaxb
features:install camel-blueprint
features:install camel-cxf
```

Comment: Thanks, But where should I find the "mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.9.0/xml/features" I couldnt see this anywhere in maven repo or in jbossfuse server package. I couldn't see any version of camel features.

Comment: I am using JBOSS Fuse and I tried "features:chooseurl camel" and got "The container is managed by fabric, please use fabric:profile-edit", then i used "fabric:profile-edit --repositories mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.10.0.redhat-60024/xml/features" and there is no features listed for "war, cxf, camel-kaxb, camel-blueprint, camel-cxf"

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I don't know FUSE fabric. Did you try to add the Camel feature with `features:addUrl mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.9.0/xml/features` as stated in the Camel documentation?

Comment: Its working in jboss fuse. All this commands are running without any problem... There must be some configuration in jboss fuse which causes this problem...

Comment: I tried executing this commands after setting the server again, I mean new one. Its working without any problem. But, I have no idea why it was not working before in my server.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I went through all the steps stated above to find out it still does not work in blueprint.

Strangely as soon as the route was dropped in the spring xml and taken out of blueprint everything started working like a magic.

Answer (score 0):

Tried camel-cxf instead cxf and worked with blueprint